# Show that $λ(f(E))=0$ implies $f'= 0$ a.e. on $E$.

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification, lebesgue-measure

I am trying to solve Ex 7:9.3 of Bruckner, et al 's book on real analysis, which is :

> Let $f$ be continuously differentiable on $[a, b]$, and let $E$ be
> Lebesgue measurable. Prove that $λ(f(E)) = 0$ if and only if $f'= 0$
> a.e. on $E$.

Now, because $f$ is differentiable so is measurable thus $λ(f(E)) = 0$. The reason is the following fact which is mentioned in another exercise of the same book :

> Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be measurable and let $Z = {\{x : f'(x)=0}\}$. Then $λ(f(Z)) = 0$.

For the other direction, the only thing in the book I can relate is Lemma 7.9. but still it is irrelevant because of different hypotheses. How can one prove that $f'=0$ a.e. on E for this conditions? Because Lemma 7.9. especially doesn't assume $E$ being measurable.

In a couterpositive way of proving i.e. $f'\ne 0$ would be change of signs too.

Answer (score 1):

$(\Leftarrow)$ If $f$ continuous differentiable on $[a,b]$, then $f$ is measurable and differentiable at each point of $E$, then by Lemma 7.10 in Bruckner's Real Analysis, we have $\lambda^*(f(E))=0$ , so $\lambda(f(E))=0$ .

$(\Rightarrow)$ First, note that, if $g=-f$, then, for any $A$,  $\lambda^*(f(A)) = \lambda^*(g(A))$.

Now, given $x \in [a,b]$, suppose $f'(x) \ne 0$. If $f'(x)<0$, we can replace $f$ by $-f$, so, we can assume, without loss of generality, that $f'(x)>0$. Since $f'$ is continuous, there is $c_x, d_x \in \Bbb Q$, such that $c_x<d_x$, $x\in [c_x,d_x]$ and $f'(y) > f'(x)/2$, for all $y\in [c_x,d_x]$. So $f$ is strictly increasing in $[c_x,d_x]$. So, using Lemma 7.4 in Bruckner's Real Analysis, we have
$$0=\lambda(f(E))=\lambda^*(f(E))\geq  \lambda^*(f(E\cap [c_x,d_x]))\geq \frac{f'(x)}{2} \lambda^*(E\cap [c_x,d_x])$$
So, $\lambda^*(E\cap [c_x,d_x])=0$.

Let $C=\{x \in [a,b] : f'(x) \ne 0 \}$, then $C \cap E \subseteq \bigcup_{x \in C} (E\cap [c_x,d_x])$, however, this union has at most countable many distinct sets, because $c_x, d_x \in \Bbb Q$. So, we can choose $D \subseteq C$, $D$ countable, such that
$$C \cap E \subseteq \bigcup_{x \in C} (E\cap [c_x,d_x]) = \bigcup_{x \in D} (E\cap [c_x,d_x])$$
Since for each $x \in C$ (and so, for each $x \in D$), we have that $\lambda^*(E\cap [c_x,d_x])=0$, we can conclude that
$$\lambda^*(C \cap E)\leq \lambda^* \left (\bigcup_{x \in D} (E\cap [c_x,d_x] \right ) \leq \sum_{x \in D}\lambda^*(E\cap [c_x,d_x])=0 $$
It means $f'=0$ a.e. on $E$.